# conversion of distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

Find distribution function  $F_Y(y)$

$$F_X(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         \frac{x}{\theta} &  \  0\leq x \leq \theta;\\
        1 & x \geq \theta \end{array} \right.  $$

Given that $Y=\min(X,\frac{\theta}{2})$

Can anyone please explain me how we convert distribution function?

**Edit:** I don't want to solve this particular problem, I want to know how these types of problems are solved.

**Edit 2:**  If necessary one can change the question to another random variable $Y$ or to a different distribution function $F_X(x)$ so that I can understand more about my problem.

Comment: First question you should ask yourself: in which real interval does $Y$ take its values?

Comment: 0 to $\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: Right. Second question: are there values $y$ in this interval such that $P(Y=y)\ne0$?

Comment: In this  whole  interval (0,$\frac{\theta}{2}$), $P(Y=y) \neq 0$ because for $x \leq \frac{\theta}{2}$ $F_Y=F_X$

Comment: Aaargh. No. There is exactly one value of $y$ such that $P(Y=y)\ne0$. Can you find it? (Note that, by contrast, $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$.)

Comment: Please stop modifying the content of your question. If you want to add something, add it at the end.

Comment: @Did $P(X=x) =0 $ for $x< 0 $ and $x> \theta$

Comment: And $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$ in $[0,\theta]$.

Comment: in $[0,\theta]$ $P(X=x)=0$ because distribution function is of continuous type???

Comment: Yes, so $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$. Now, to $P(Y=y)$, is this always zero as well? What do you think?

Comment: Y is also of absolute continuous type that's why $P(Y=y) =0$

Comment: *Y is also of absolute continuous type*... Why? Please THINK, maths is not about reciting mantras, you know.

Comment: graph of $min(X,\frac{\theta}{2})$ is straight line X and after $\frac{\theta}{2}$ it is constant that's why Y is also of absolute continuous type

Comment: ?? You might want to explain what this has to do with the question. No, Y is not of absolutely continuous type.

Comment: $P(\frac{\theta}{2}<x<{\theta})$ is concentrated at point $\frac{\theta}{2}$ in case of random variable y that's why $P(y=\frac{\theta}{2})$ in not zero value. Is that the reason Y is not of absolute continuous type??

Comment: Aaaah... Indeed "something" happens at $\frac12\theta$... Can you compute directly $P(Y=\frac12\theta)$?

Comment: yes P(Y=$\frac{\theta}{2}$)=$P(\frac{\theta}{2}\leq x \leq\theta)$ = $F_X(\theta)-F_X(\frac{\theta}{2}^-)$=$1-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yep. Now to the part $Y\lt\frac12\theta$. Can you compute the density for this part of the distribution?

Comment: I got the answer...Is it always possible to determine whether $Y$ is of absolute continuous type or not by just looking at Y=(some function of x)

Comment: If $Y=u(X)$ and the function $u$ is constant on an interval $I$ such that $P[X\in I]\ne0$, then you can be sure that there is a Dirac part in the distribution of $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're solved mostly by **definition-chasing**.

$F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\le y)$.  That is a definition.

$\Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(\min\{X,\theta/2\}\le y)$.  That is a definition.

$\min\{X,\theta/2\}\le y$ if and only if $X\le y\text{ or }\theta/2\le y$.  That is an immediate corollary of a definition.  Thus we have
$$
F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }y\ge\theta/2, \\ ? & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
So suppose $0\le y < \theta/2$.  Then $\min\{X,\theta/2\}\le y$ if and only if $X\le y$, and the probability of that is $y/\theta$.  Si
$$
F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }y\ge\theta/2, \\ y/\theta & \text{if }0\le y <\theta/2,  \\ ? & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
It's not hard to see why the "otherwise" value must be $0$.

Don't try to solve problems like this by applying an algorithm.  Use logic.

Answer (score -1):

For $y < \theta/2$, $F_Y = F_X$ is the same since $Y = X$. We see that for $y \geq \theta/2$, $F_Y = 1$ since all values of $Y$ are less than or equal to $\theta/2$.